# How to update the ng-href URl on $scope change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-href

I'm  looking to update the 'ng-href' url on scope value from controller.Initially on page load url is inserted fine. But then 
when i change the scope that URL should be updated

```
<a ng-href=={{selectedValue}} /a>

//in my controller
$scope.selectedValue = "www.google.com"

//need to update this url in this function
otherButtonFn = function(){
//want to Update the url here
$scope.selectedValue =  "www.yahoo.com"
}

//ng-href is loading initial url but not updating when $scope is called
  <a ng-href=="www.google.com" href=""www.google.com" /a>
```

Here i want to update the url with "www.yahoo.com" when that function is called.

Comment: close your anchor tag correctly like `<a href="test/url">Test</a>`

Comment: thanks, but i'm using scope instead of $rootscope

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the anchor tag which has double == and no "" around it. Please see updated example below:

```
<a ng-href="{{selectedValue}}">Link Name</a>

$scope.selectedValue = "www.google.com";


$scope.otherButtonFn = function(){
   $scope.selectedValue =  "www.yahoo.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.something = "somewhere";
  $scope.changeSomething = function(){
    $scope.something = "somewhere else";
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <a ng-href="{{something}}">{{something}}</a>
    <button ng-click="changeSomething()">Change</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not able to reproduce the problem as stated.

Comment: Thing is that button is in other template. Though it is using the same controller

Comment: I made a silly mistake, i used $rootscope for global scope and it works. Thanks thought